# I'm getting this error when fly over the chart: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lineWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'am using React 16 and I'm getting this error when fly over the chart: [screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYrmv.png)
I reinstalled the library but the error is still there. Pleas anyone know what it is?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lineWidth' of undefined

[image]

My Component:

```
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

const options = {
   chart: {
       type: 'pie'
   },
   title: {
       text: 'Tableau de bord'
   },
   series: [
       {
       data: [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6]
       }
   ]
};
 
class WidgetIndicator extends Component {
   render() {
       return (
       <div className="widget-grid-content__indicator">
       <HighchartsReact
           highcharts={Highcharts}
           constructorType={'stockChart'}
           options={options}
       />
       </div>
       )
   };
}
 
export default WidgetIndicator;
```

Answer (score 1):

That problem is a Highstock bug and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13868

As a workaround disable splitted tooltip and set at least an empty configuration object for marker inactive state:

```
    tooltip: {
        split: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6],
        marker: {
            states: {
                inactive: {
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/09z8tcnq/

Comment: Thanks you ppotaczek !